# Broadcasting a quiz event

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, spring

HI all currently we created a quiz page with spring and Jquery, everything is working fine but there is some requirement where, when a team captain attends a quiz in one machine, their team members would like to view the progress of their respective captains(like a live relay of questions and answers they choose) from other PCs. So how can i broadcast the event of one page, or is there a better way to design the solution

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you'll need to implement some `push` technology in your app. The way you're going to do it is mostly depends on your server stack and technologies.

If you're using `Java` you might want to check out [Vert.x](http://vertx.io/)
In case you're using `Nodejs` then it will be very easy to use [Socket.io](http://socket.io/)

you may read more about pros/cons here: [Node.js or Vert.x for Push Notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27012521/node-js-or-vert-x-for-push-notifications)

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need a [Websocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) for that one.  It can be a bit complex to implement on your backend(depending a LOT on what your backend is...) but a simple messager should not be a big deal.